# How to define complex shapes in SQL?

Tags: hive, hdfs, polygon, shapes, querying

I'm working with a flight-trajectory dataset. Containing a lot of longitude and latitude points. I only want to extract, from a large database, the points that are relevant to my analysis, e.g. points withing the Netherlands airspace.

Please see attatched image. 
[image: ![nlairspace](https://imgur.com/cowoFCn)]

In order to define a boundary like the orange lines one would write the following code:

```
SELECT ROUND(lat, 6) AS lat,
       ROUND(lon, 6) AS long,
  FROM state_vectors_data4 sv
 WHERE lat BETWEEN 50.1 AND 54.1 AND 
       lon BETWEEN 2.2 AND 8.2;
```

Thereby defining the four points in the corners and extracting all the data withing this square. 
Is there a methodology of capturing all the points within a polygon? Say within the area draw between the red lines?
Or even better is there a methodology of capturing all the points within a 'border interval', say the area between the red and the blue lines?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Some DBMSes have GeoSpatial extensions which should cover your needs

Comment: The database is a HDFS

***
OpenSky Network Impala Shell
********************************************************************************                                                                             ***
[hadoop-29:21000] > SHOW DATABASES
                  > ;
+---------+-----------------------+
| name    | comment               |
+---------+-----------------------+
| default | Default Hive database |
| opensky |                       |
+---------+-----------------------+